# Phoronix Test Suit does not display sensor readings

Tags: test-suite, almalinux

I have a problem with the output of sensor readings after a Phoronix Test Suite finished. Sensors are available if output is made via system-sensors.

```
cpu.freq         CPU Frequency (CPU126):                      2600.00 Megahertz
cpu.freq         CPU Frequency (CPU127):                      2600.00 Megahertz
cpu.peak-freq    CPU Peak Freq (Highest CPU Core Frequency):  2611    Megahertz
cpu.power        CPU Power Consumption:                       203.23  Watts
cpu.temp         CPU Temperature:                             59.00   Celsius
```

Phoronix writes Sensors To Be Logged before starting the

```
Sensors To Be Logged:
   - CPU Temperature.
```

Once the test is completed, this sensor reading is not visible in the results.

```
Finishing System Sensor Monitoring Process

    Do you want to view the text results of the testing (Y/n): Y
stress78
2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6338 testing with (10.29.22 BIOS) and astdrmfb on AlmaLinux 8.8 via the Phoronix Test Suite.


2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6338 - astdrmfb:

    Processor: 2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6338 @ 3.20GHz (64 Cores / 128 Threads), Memory: 32 x 64 GB DDR4-2933MT/s Hynix HMAA8GR7MJR4N-WM, Disk: 2 x 480GB SAMSUNG MZ7LH480 + 3 x 18000GB Western Digital WUH721818AL + 3 x 3841GB INTEL SSDSC2KB03 + 3 x 1920GB SAMSUNG MZ7LH1T9 + 3 x 16001GB Seagate ST16000NM001G-2K, Graphics: astdrmfb

    OS: AlmaLinux 8.8, Kernel: 5.15.137 (x86_64), File-System: xfs, Screen Resolution: 1024x768


    Stress-NG 0.16.04
    Test: CPU Stress
    Bogo Ops/s > Higher Is Better
    2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6338 - astdrmfb . 88127.41 |=============================================================================================================================================

    Would you like to upload the results to OpenBenchmarking.org (y/n):
```

I tried to display different sensors. If I write MONITOR=all, only CPU.usage and Disk usage will be displayed. There will be no other indications. I don't know how to solve this. Google and the Phoronix forum did not help.

I've tried adding sensor checks one at a time. I only see the result from cpu.usage and disk.write